# Launch Jenkins job from script (shell) with file parameter

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to launch a jenkins Job from shell script with file parameter.

it is easy with a string parameter but not with file:

```
curl -u $username:$password -X POST https://$jenkins_url/job/$job_name/build\?token\=$some_token
```

Any idea please.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following url: http://server/job/myjob/buildWithParameters?PARAMETER=Value
Look this [link](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build)